# Multiple JDialogs modal to parent?

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jdialog

I have a JFrame that launches a dialog on a button click. I would like a different button to launch 2+ dialogs that are modal to the parent frame (to allow side by side comparison and interaction of the 2 dialogs but not allow the user to interact with the parent frame). Is it possible to do this using dialogs or should I resort to frames?

Comment: Did you check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html ?

Comment: Make one dialog modal to the JFrame and the second dialog created from the first, and make it non-modal. The first dialog will lock the JFrame, but the 2nd dialog won't lock the first since it's non-modal.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels What do you mean by second dialog created from the first? So launch a second dialog using the first dialog? If I close the first one, wouldnt the second dialog still be there and it isnt modal to the frame?

Answer (score 2):

Again, you could make one JDialog modal, and set its parent window to the main JFrame, and make the 2nd dialog modeless, and set its parent window to the first dialog. Something like:

```
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MultipleDialogs {
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            final JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Main JFrame");
            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mainFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Two Dialogs") {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JDialog dialog1 = new JDialog(mainFrame, "Dialog 1 -- modal", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                    dialog1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
                    dialog1.pack();
                    dialog1.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                    JDialog dialog2 = new JDialog(dialog1, "Dialog 2 -- nonmodal", ModalityType.MODELESS);
                    dialog2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
                    dialog2.pack();
                    dialog2.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                    dialog2.setVisible(true);

                    dialog1.setVisible(true);
                }
            }));

            mainFrame.add(panel);
            mainFrame.pack();
            mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Make sure that you set the modal dialog visible **after** displaying the first dialog.

Comment: I want the second dialog to be modal to the parent frame, not to the first dialog. So if I close dialog 1, dialog 2 should still be opened and it is modal to the frame. Is this possible with dialogs?

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for. Basically I set the dialog modal to false and on launch I set the parent frame to be disabled. Then I keep count of the number of dialogs open and when all of them are closed, I re-enable it.